# Is it possible to open modern item edit form panel from custom SPFx webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

Is it possible to open EditForm panel from my SPFx webpart? Something like in list view, if an item is selected, side panel appears with read-only properties and a button "edit all" enables user to open panel for edit. I would like to re-use this button in my own webpart. If possible, I would also like to re-use the read only box with item properties in side panel.

[image: Explanation]

Comment: do you find any way?

Comment: No, not really. It seems that the item detail popup component is not reusable.

Comment: This is a very clunky solution, by using the propertypane itself: https://julieturner.net/2017/07/creating-a-property-pane-for-editing-items-in-your-spfx-web-parts/ it's hard to maintain

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to export this exact component, however you could go about making your own version with SPFx. The side panel, link, and text field components are all available as React components in the Microsoft [Fabric UI library](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric) and would be able to be wired up to your web part.

The context of whatever you've selected can be passed as `props` to your edit panel.

Comment: Problem is the Fluent UI (formerly Fabric UI) offers a "Panel" that is overlapping the entire site and not using the SPPropertyPane container of SharePoint that does not overlap and is basically an additional column on the body.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do something similar.  At the moment I am constructing a URL to the items display form (which in Modern allows users who have edit permissions to update properties as well) and rendering that link in an iFrame within a side panel.  It works but is not very snappy (then again neither is the OOTB info panel) and it shows back-links to the list, which I'd rather hide.

Answer (score 0):

This might require extra hours of development. I have a similar task with SPFx and I ended up creating my custom view